# Angular EventEmitter does not emit any changes of an array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-event-emitter, server-communication

here is my code:

notes.service.ts

```
      private notes: Array<Note> = [];
      notesChanged = new EventEmitter<Note[]>();
     
      getNotes() {
        this.getData();
        console.log('getNotes()', this.notes);
        return this.notes;
      }

      getData() {
         this.http.get<Note[]>(this.url).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                 this.notes = data;
                 this.notesChanged.emit(this.notes);
            }
         );
      }
```

notes.component.ts

```
      notes: Array<Note> = [];
 
      ngOnInit(): void {
          this.notes = this.notesData.getNotes();
          this.notesData.notesChanged.subscribe(
              (notes: Note[]) => this.notes = notes
          );
      }
```

notes.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of notes" class="col-md-4">
   <a [routerLink]="['/note', item.id]" class="note-link">
      <div class="note-body text-center">
          <h4>{{item.title}}</h4>
          <p>{{item.text}}</p>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Notes are not displayed after loading in browser, only if I navigate away and then go back to notes, only then they will be displayed.

console.log('getNotes()', this.notes); shows that the array is empty right after loading in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `getNotes()` method. It sends an asynchronous request by calling `getData()`, does not wait for the result and can return either an empty list (if it didn't have time to be completed) or data from the server (what you see by browsing sometimes). The way for you to go is to return `notes` in `getData()` after subscribtion.

Answer (score 0):

console.log('getNotes()', this.notes); is triggered before the getData call to the api gets the results. That's why you don get anything in the log on page load.

Can you show the notes.component.html?

Comment: I added notes.component.html to my question, thank you.